# Certain apps lose all internet connectivity until reboot

Tags: samsung, connection-issues, internet, bugs, samsung-galaxy-s-10

*I have put off asking the question for some time because I know it is vague and terrible to debug so I welcome your help refining the question as well as potential solutions.*

A range of certain apps will report no internet connectivity and get stuck in that state no matter how good my WiFi and/or mobile data connection or if I force stop and/or clear their cache. So far:

- facebook
- instagram
- onedrive
- toktok
- aliexpress
- whatsapp (i get the clock symbol)
- viber

Normally only one of these at a time, sometimes two. Never all! (so not just general connectivity issues). I ignore them for a day or two and they never recover connectivity. Chrome is never affected (yet) and I still get push notifications for said apps.

I am technical and have pondered dodgy dns but apps get in this state on and off Wi-Fi which should mean different dns servers, not just a quirk on my home network. I don't use a mobile VPN. I do have a work profile. My phone is a standard build Samsung S10 that behaved normally for over a year until recently.

Drives me mad because all advice out there is for fixing general/global connectivity as people always complain about that and turn it off and on again is a good solution for any single app getting into a funky state but this feels dumb, like the OS is caching/blocking/blacklisting something and I kinda wanna blame samsung or put on a tin hat and blame the government... yeah I am mocking myself now :)

So, any suggestions?

*Ahhh!* I just had *two messaging apps* go quitely into this offline mode. Toggle wifi, nothing. Toggle flight mode, nothing. I *restart* and *instantly* these send and retrieve messages. If i cannot relay on my phone to communicate it is useless!

Comment: In my opinion it's more easy for you to troubleshoot the problem, instead of others making guesses for you. You can use Termux or `adb shell` to use `ping`, `dig` etc. to see if connectivity works normally. If luckily the Termux app also loses connectivity you'll get to the root cause very quickly. Or if root is available you can switch to one of affected apps' UID and do troubleshooting. Might be a problem in your routing table, IP settings or firewall rules, or a bug in kernel which removes an app's UID from `3003` group, or one of other usual problems faced on any Linux OS.

Comment: Yeah it really feels like I need to get out `adb shell` however I ping and dig would only help if I debug the specific APIs of the apps. I will consider if i am capable of this. And then what? I don't know how routing or firewall issues could occur on a non-rooted android phone though...? Essentially i think I am searching for anyone who has seen these symptoms on a phone before - has experienced this issue

Comment: Wild guess - try turning off battery optimization and see if it helps //I know it's not logical but just saying..

Comment: Valid guess. Battery optimisation is off and none of the affected apps are in `Background usage limits` > `Sleeping` or `Deep sleeping apps`

Comment: Update: It appears to have been a intermittent issue probably due to a particular OS version ... TL;DR keep your phone up to date and fingers crossed